# Filtro adicional para groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

O seguinte código agrupa meu DF por algumas colunas
`f0219.groupby(['Matricula', 'Nome', 'Rubrica', 'Valor', 'CodigoRendimentoDesconto', 'Tiporubrica']).Rubrica.count()` e conta quantas vezes a coluna Rubrica aparece em cada agrupamento. O resultado desse código pode ser conferido na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero que, se a coluna Tiporubrica for igual a "2", ele some o que está na coluna Valor, e exiba o resultado dessa soma em uma terceira coluna.
Além disso, eu percebi que, ao executar o comando acima do groupby, o resultado não é exibido em um dataframe, e eu gostaria que fosse, pois pretendo trabalhar no resultado como um dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

A solução para esse caso não precisa de uma condição. Você pode simplesmente adicionar mais um método de agrupamento nesse groupby, no caso, o 'sum' para a coluna 'Valor'.

Alem disso, para retornar um dataframe, basta resetar o index.

Assim:

```
agg = {'Rubrica': 'count', 'Valor': 'sum'}

f0219.groupby(['Matricula', 'Nome']).apply(agg).reset_index()
```

Se precisar das outras colunas, basta colocar quais colunas e quais metodos de agrupamento no dict 'agg'.

Espero ter ajudado :)